# Dynamic theming in angular

Tags: css, angular

I made an app in angular 4.
One of the feature allows the user to choose theme's color with a color picker.
So when a user logs in the app, a webservice is sending me the color code and I have to adapt elements color based on that (mainly buttons, menu's background color, etc).

In my login component I've got the hexadecimal code in the applications array and I store it in the localStorage :

```
this.loginService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(user => {
    this.loginService.getToken(this.email, this.password)
        .subscribe(resp => {
            localStorage.setItem('token', resp.accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem('login', user.username);
            localStorage.setItem('name', user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname);
            localStorage.setItem('password', this.password);
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
            localStorage.setItem('userId', user.id.toString());
            this.loginService.getApplications().subscribe(applications => {
                if (localStorage.getItem('applicationId') === '' || localStorage.getItem('applicationId') === null) {
                    localStorage.setItem('applicationId', applications.applications[0].id.toString());
                    localStorage.setItem('color', applications.applications[0].color);
                }
                localStorage.setItem('applications', JSON.stringify(applications));
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
            });
        });
});
```

I want to, for instance, override my "action" class to my localStorage color item.

```
<a class="btn action float-right ml20" [routerLink]="['/client/create']">{{'ADD_CLIENT' | translate}}</a>
```

Is there a way for me to do this ? I could change it in the inline style property but I don't want to do it for all the elements I have in the app.

Thanks !

Comment: I am sure it is possible to do, but as it stands now your question is too broad to answer. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, what information would help you to answer ?

Comment: Please read what's on the link I provided

Comment: I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In my app component I added this :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.color = localStorage.getItem('color');
    const css = '.action {background-color: ' + this.color + ';}';
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    head.appendChild(style);
}
```